# Page not found error for an image in the protected question blog page

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, protected-questions

There is a "Page not found" error on the [Proctected questions blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/07/new-protected-question-status/). I navigated to the blog post from the [Protect questions privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) page.

When clicking on the image in the page, it navigate to the "Page not found" page.

> [image: Page not found in blog]

When inspecting the element of the image, the `href` is pointing to `/images/wordpress/`. That path does not exist.

```
<p>
    <a href="/images/wordpress/superuser-deleted-answers.png">
        <img src="https://zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/superuser-deleted-answers-small.png" alt="">
    </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for alerting us to this issue.  I've corrected the link for this image.